# RealTime Download Statistics Viewer

Tags: web-applications, mobile, web, web-statistics

I have a Infotainment Portal. We provide Music, Movies for Mobile Download. I want to see the Download Statistics & Visitor Statistics. I prefer Woopra for Visitor Statisyics but need something very cheap or free.

My problem is my site is for Mobile Viewing. Many user may not be having JavaDisabled, so please suggest a fix...

Answer (score 0):

[Piwik](http://piwik.org/) is a great open-source web analytics software written in PHP and MySQL. It has a feature that uses image tags to track visitors, however less information can be collected that way.

I'm not sure if Google Analytics collects information from users with javascript disabled, but they are a cheap alternative as well.

Comment: Thank U. But friend, I need something that could give me the control over Download. Like kicking a user, viewing all downloads with visitor information etc...